# Clock waveform does not show in EDAplayground

Tags: verilog, clock, edaplayground

When trying to get the Clock waveform to display in EDA Playground I get the error

> Execution interrupted or reached maximum runtime.

How do I get the wave form to show?

[Code on EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Ehm):

```
module test;
  reg clk;
  
  initial 
    begin
      $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
      $dumpvars(1);
      clk=0;
    end
  
  always
    begin
      #1 clk<=~clk;
    end
  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

There was no `$finish` so as the sim ran indefinitely and was killed by the server. Adding #100 $finish; to your main test program would give you 50 clocks example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/RvN).

```
module test;
  reg clk;

  initial 
    begin
      $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
      $dumpvars(1);
      clk=0;
      #100 $finish; //<-- End simulation
    end

  always
    begin
      #1 clk<=~clk;
    end

endmodule
```